# Initial load of Kafka stream data with windowed join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a Windowed Join between two streams, let's say a 7 day window.

On initial load, all records in the DB (via kafka connect source connector) are being loaded to the streams.  It seems then that ALL records end up in the window state store for those first 7 days as the producer/ingested timestamps are all in current time vs. a field (like create_time) that might be in the message value.

Is there a recommended way to balance the initial load against the Windows of the join?

Comment: Which TimestampExtractor did you use for the window?

Comment: At the moment, the default one. I thought about replacing it and substituting the create_time value, but then I was thinking that it would be outside the time window and the joins would never happen

Comment: Are you suggesting that if I have record A and join record A with date 1 yr ago, and record B which joins to B with dates of last week ... If I use a custom timestamp extractor, with a window of pretend one month ... A and A' would match b/c their timestamp dates are within a month and B and B' would also match b/c their dates are within a month of each other?

Comment: I'm just saying if you actually want an actual month rather than all data, you'll need to adjust that setting

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is what records do you want to join to each other? And what timestamp the source connector sets as record timestamp (might also depend on the topic configuration, `[log.]message.timestamp.type`.

The join is executed based on whatever the `TimestampExtractor`  returns. By default, that is the record timestamp. If you want to base the join on some other timestamp, a custom timestampe extractor is the way to go.

If you want to get processing time semantics, you may want to use the `WallclockTimestampExtractor` though.